# Assembly (MASM) Dot Prefix Syntax Errors

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm in school, assignment due tomorrow. Been able to figure the first few weeks out through theory alone, but it's getting harder and would like to test my code before submitting it. I've been unable to get anything working due to syntax errors and such on the first few lines of the code template...

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
```

All of the above lines come back with an error, A2008 for the first 4, A1000 for the 5th. Unfortunately, professor isn't responding to my emails and next class will be too late, if he even shows up. Any help getting my code (ANY code) to work in VS would be much appreciated. I found NASM emulators online but nothing for MASM. Also, I have already found the wikihow (https://www.wikihow.com/Use-MASM-in-Visual-Studio-2022_) but still getting those errors.

Edit: Got it figured out. Thanks, Michael. I was able to also find the Getting Started tutorial for the book at https://asmirvine.com/gettingStartedVS2017/index.htm

Should I be worried, though, that my Windows Defender pops every time I test a question answer? Keeps saying a Wacatac Trojan has been detected...Maybe I got a fake Irvine or it's been compromised?

Comment: Get rid of the first 3 lines and move the include up to the top of the file. The Irive include file already contains those directives.

Comment: Any chance this is Visual Studio and your project is set for x86-64 (Win 64-bit) and not x86 (Win 32-bit)? You will also need Irvine32 installed.

Comment: I suspect your virus program likely is reporting a false positive. You aren't alone: https://www.reddit.com/r/computerviruses/comments/qffc5g/help_please_irvine32inc_trojanwin32wacatacbml/  . Do you know what things you changed in your program that solved your problem? Was it at all related to 64 and 32-bit builds?

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the virus. Figured out those are just virus detection names, not file names, and Windows thought I was the intruder.

Comment: Also, all I did was download and open the 32-bit project off asmirvine site, 2017 version is on the website, the 2022 version is on Irvine's GitHub. I guess it has all the setting and such needed to make it work. I also had to Project -> Project Properties -> MMA (bottom property) -> General -> and at the Include Paths line put where i saved the Irvine library